# Basic Change Set Question

Tags: apex, change-set

Scenario question- say I created a outbound change set and did not deploy it.

I then decided to update the controller that is in the change set.

Do I need to remove and add back in the newly updated controller before I deploy? Or does the change set update as you update?

Comment: The change set takes the metadata snapshot at the time it is deployed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you upload the outbound change set a snapshot of the metadata is packaged together for deployment in the target org. After that you will need to clone the change set and upload again to pickup any subsequent changes.

Comment: You just beat 3 people. I think that's a record.

Comment: Pew Pew: Fastest gun in the west :)

Comment: Fastest *fingers* in the west!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fingers... Great idea! I was finding this gun really awkward to type with.

Comment: You area dangerous, dangerous man. Ah the imagery of trying to hit keys with a gun in each hand brings a whole new meaning to hunt and peck!